# Nesting AND and OR operation with MongoID

Tags: sinatra, mongoid, mongoid3

I'm trying to figure out how to nest an AND and OR operation with MongoID, like so (taken from something that I used to use with MongoMapper):

```
{
:$and=> [
    {
        :$or => [
            {"name"=> "joe"}, {"name" => "randy" }
    {
        :$or=> [
            {"something" => "else" }, {"another" => "thing" }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I'm not too terribly familiar with the way union and intersection works, but the kicker is that each child within the `AND` is optional/not guaranteed. In other words, each query within `AND` is programmatic, there could be 2 items to check against, 1 item, etc.

I thought about doing something like this:

```
Model.or({ :name => "...." }).union.or( :something => "...." })
```

But, the only problem with that is I'm not sure on the best practice of constructing the query based on user input. I have a sinatra-based application that acts as an API point for my users that is connecting to my MongoID models, and I'd like for users to be able to construct queries like this (maybe not this complicated) over the API.

I'm migrating over to MongoID from MongoMapper for various reasons, but with MongoMapper these queries were a little simpler because everything, such as nested `and` and `or` operators, are supported within a `where` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that MongoID (well, more specifically Origin::Query) supports Mongo selector syntax within many of their DSL functions, like so:

```
Model.where(   { "name" => { "$or" => [ "betsy", "charles" ] }   )
```

So gathering from my above example, you can just do this:

```
Model.all_of(    [
    {
        "$or" => [
            {"name"=> "joe"}, {"name" => "randy" }
    },
    {
        "$or" => [
            {"something" => "else" }, {"another" => "thing" }
        ]
    }
]
```